# Javascript getElementsByName.value not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple javascript program bit it isn't working. Kindly help.
In eclipse I have created a dynamic web project and in DD my welcome file is index.jsp.
Given below is my code for index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Duncan'S</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nameSubmit() {
    alert(document.getElementsByName("username").value);
}
function CakeNumber() {
    alert(document.getElementsByName("numOfCake").value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myservlet.do">
    <table>
        <tr>
              <td>Name:</td>
              <td><input type="text" id="name" name="username" size="10"
                onchange="nameSubmit();"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>Number Of Duncan's Cake:</td>
              <td><input type="text" id="numOfDunCake" name="numOfCake"
                size="5" onchange="CakeNumber();"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code both the functions are returning undefined.....!!How can I get the real value??

Comment: You are using `username` instead of `name`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have mentioned Wrong id

```
alert(document.getElementById("name").value);
```

if you want to use **`name`** attribute then

```
alert(document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value);
```

**Updates:**

```
input type="text" id="name" name="username"
```

id is different from name

Comment: Praveen this expression is giving the right value for the function CakeNumber() So i guess it somehow works. Please corrext me if I am wrong. What should i use to fet the value??

Comment: @user2583134 no in `CakeNumber()` both name and id are having same names and hence it is working see this `input type="text" id="numOfDunCake" name="numOfDunCake"`

Comment: @Praveen I tried using GetElementByName() and changed the value of both name and id, taking value of name as an argument in the function but still it does not work and this time the 1st function is returning value as undefined and the second function never gets called :(

Comment: @Praveen I have used the command said by you but now both of them are returning 'undefined'. What should I do?

Comment: @user2583134 sorry, it has to be `alert(document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value);` check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88krg/

Comment: @Praveen Thanks a lot friend..It worked this time. One more thing how can i get the value by using id...?? :)

Comment: @user2583134 similar what you have  done for `CakeNumber`.  See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88krg/1/.   The problem you have referred name instead of id.  Hope you understand.

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementsByName("name")` will get several elements called by same name .
`document.getElementsByName("name")[Number]` will get one of them.
`document.getElementsByName("name")[Number].value` will get the value of paticular element.

The key of this question is this:
The name of elements is not unique, it is usually used for several input elements in the form.
On the other hand, the id of the element is unique, which is the only definition for a particular element in a html file.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/pn92429e) is the example for having one or more checkboxes value. If you have two or more checkboxes and need values then this would really help.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var selchbox = [];
  var inputfields = document.getElementsByName("myCheck");
  var ar_inputflds = inputfields.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < ar_inputflds; i++) {
    if (inputfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputfields[i].checked == true)
      selchbox.push(inputfields[i].value);
  }
  return selchbox;

}

document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function() {
  var selchb = myFunction();
  console.log(selchb);
}
```

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="UK">United Kingdom
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="USA">United States
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="IL">Illinois
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="MA">Massachusetts
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="UT">Utah

<input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" />
```