# put variable value in textbox without onclick button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**I have made code with comments below:**

which is storing value from url=> ../webdev/dummy.html?foo=**quora**, now my query is I want to show **quora** in textbox at the page load only, I don't want to use onclick function.please guide  me :)

**dummy.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  var foo = getParameterByName('foo');

  document.getElementsByName('subject').Value = foo; // this is I am thinking of to store value in textbox id="subject"
</script>

<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" readonly="true" />
<!-- textbox to display "quora" -->
```

it is not displaying any value in textbox

Comment: `.Value = foo` ===> `[0].value = foo[0].value`

Comment: `getElementsByName` will return you a NodeList. Use `[0].value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getElementsByName.value not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834804/javascript-getelementsbyname-value-not-working)

Comment: can anyone tell me how to set visibility of  drop down tab according to the value passed in url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the code

`document.getElementsByName('subject').Value = foo;`

with

`document.getElementById('subject').value = foo;`

In case you want to call it onload of the page you can use the following code,

`body.onload=function(){//call your function};`

or

`window.onload=function(){//call the function}`

Comment: Why can you not use `getElementsByName`?

Comment: yes you can use document.getElementsByName it will return a nodelist ,since he is already using an id ,getElementByid will be easier to use since it returns the exact element

Comment: @GraveyardQueen hey I am girl(since he is already :p :p :p) ....btw exact solution...thanks a lot

Comment: @GraveyardQueen just a pointer, its a bad practice to use `window.onload=function`. You should use `window.addEventListener('load', function)`

Answer (score 1):

As commented before, `.getElementsByName` will return you a `NodeList`. You will either have to loop over it of use specific index.

Also if you only have 1 element, I'd suggest using `document.querySelector` as this will return first matched element.

#### Sample

```js
var nodeList = document.getElementsByName('subject');
console.log(nodeList)
console.log(nodeList[0])

var el = document.querySelector('input[name="subject"]');
console.log(el)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" readonly="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a working sample: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mat2e/8mhcdp3g/1/)

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) {
    url = window.location.href;
  }
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var foo = getParameterByName('foo', 'www.google.de?foo=hugo');

document.getElementsByName('subject')[0].value = foo; // this is I am thinking of to store value in textbox id="subject"
```

```html
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" readonly="true" />
<!-- textbox to display "quora" -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **getElementById** instead of `getElementsByName` and always *run/ include* JavaScript code *after DOM components are loaded*.

Ideally HTML should always load styles/DOM before any script.

For more information, refer: [Where is the best place to put  tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

```html
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" readonly="true" />

<!-- ideally script should run after html code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    url = "www.example.com/webdev/dummy.html?foo=quora" //sample snippet url
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    console.log(results[2])
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  var foo = getParameterByName('foo');
  // changing the getElementsByName to getElementById
  document.getElementById('subject').value = foo; 
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done. Just putting code is not good enough

Comment: Not much really, I used getElementById attribute instead of  getElementsByName and moved script to bottom to run after dom is loaded

Comment: I can see that, but I had to read your code to deduce it. You should explain your approach. Like why did you move script tag at the end. Why `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByName`. A person facing these issues does not have enough knowledge to differentiate and will use your code blindly. Help your fellow users with knowledge you have acquired.

Comment: Rajesh - Updated the answer. Will be more clear next time :)