# Javascript skipping the if and if else conditions and directly jumping to else condition

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and just trying my hands on to JavaScript with a simple login page.

I have created a login page using HTML and CSS and JavaScript for validations. But my JavaScript code is not working properly.

It is skipping the if conditions and directly jumping to else part and sometimes it is just validating the first if else part for username validation.

Below is my JavaScript and html code.
I am using and external JavaScript.

```js
 function ValidateSignIn() {
   //Variable declarations and initialization
   var username = document.getElementsByName("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementsByName("password").value;

   //Validation of username and password fields
   if (username == "Temp" && password == "123") {
     alert("Login Successful!!");
     window.location = "C:\Users\metyagi\Downloads\Personal data\THE SCM QUIZ\WelcomePage.html";
   } else if (username == null || username == "") {
     alert("Please enter CEC ID");
   } else if (password == null || password == "") {
     alert("Please enter Password");
   } else {
     alert("Username or Password is incorrect, Please try again!!");
   }
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The SCM Quiz Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\SignIn.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\mt\Downloads\data\test\SignIn.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Div for Logo-->
  <Div class="logo">
    <img src="images\logo.png" />
  </Div>

  <!--Div for form-->
  <Div class="loginform">
    <h3>Login </h3>
    <h6>Required fields are marked with *</h6>
    <form method="post" action="" name="SignIn">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" name="username" placeholder="Please Enter Username*">
      </br>
      </br>
      <INPUT TYPE="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password*">
      </br>
      </br>
      <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="SignIn" value="SIGN IN" onclick="ValidateSignIn()">
      <a href="ForgotPassword.html">Forgot Password?</a>
      <p class="message">Not Registered Yet? <a href="SignUp.html">Sign Up!</a>
      </P>
    </form>
  </Div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getElementsByName.value not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834804/javascript-getelementsbyname-value-not-working)

Comment: + also [good to read](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/).

Answer (score 1):

You are using document.getElementsByName("username") method ,From the name (get**Elements**ByName) of the method itself you come to know that it returns the nodelist collection with name as username. so you need to give correct index number to get the value. otherwise you can also use the getElementById() method by defining id for text field in Html.

```js
function ValidateSignIn() {

  //Variable declarations and initialization
  var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
  var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;

  //Validation of username and password fields
  if (username == "Temp" && password == "123") {
    alert("Login Successful!!");
    window.location = "C:\Users\metyagi\Downloads\Personal data\THE SCM QUIZ\WelcomePage.html";
  } else if (username == null || username == "") {
    alert("Please enter CEC ID");
  } else if (password == null || password == "") {
    alert("Please enter Password");
  } else {
    alert("Username or Password is incorrect, Please try again!!");
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The SCM Quiz Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\SignIn.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\mt\Downloads\data\test\SignIn.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Div for Logo-->
  <Div class="logo">
    <img src="images\logo.png" />
  </Div>

  <!--Div for form-->
  <Div class="loginform">
    <h3>Login </h3>
    <h6>Required fields are marked with *</h6>
    <form method="post" action="" name="SignIn">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" name="username" placeholder="Please Enter Username*">
      </br>
      </br>
      <INPUT TYPE="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password*">
      </br>
      </br>
      <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="SignIn" value="SIGN IN" onclick="ValidateSignIn()">
      <a href="ForgotPassword.html">Forgot Password?</a>

      <p class="message">Not Registered Yet? <a href="SignUp.html">Sign Up!</a>
      </P>
    </form>
  </Div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No an  _array of objects_ But according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) a _live NodeList Collection_

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to add some validation for your username and password. What you have written in the first if statement is to validate if both are valid and that should be working correctly.

```
 else if(username == null || username == ""){
    alert("Please enter CEC ID");       
}
```

This will stop further evaluation if username is not valid. In case you want to check if password too is not valid, you will need to write in a different if /else block and not in continuation of the username validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.getElementsByName` and according to your code you will get `undefined` in `username` and `password`. So you need to do this:

```
function ValidateSignIn()
{   
    //Variable declarations and initialization
    var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;

    //Validation of username and password fields
    if(username == "Temp" && password == "123")
    {
        alert("Login Successful!!");
        window.location = "C:\Users\metyagi\Downloads\Personal data\THE SCM QUIZ\WelcomePage.html";     
    }
    else if(username == null || username == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter CEC ID");       
    }
    else if (password == null || password == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter Password");     
    }   
    else
    {
        alert("Username or Password is incorrect, Please try again!!");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1:**

If you want to prevent fields not to clear on submit you can do use `preventDefault` method of the event object like this:

```
$("#Formid").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault()
})
```

OR

```
$("#Formid").submit(function(event){
      e.returnValue = false;
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.. your solution worked, but the fields username and password gets reset, any solution?

Comment: @MeenakshiTyagi Can you tell how are you submitting your form ? Are you using jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
```

or set id on your elements and try :

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate validating user input and checking user credentials to make the code clear and easy to read, please refer the code below:

```
function ValidateSignIn(){
    var hasError = false;

    //Variable declarations and initialization
    var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;

    //Validation of username and password fields
    if (!username) { // this will check null, undefined, and empty string
        hasError = true;
        alert("Please enter CEC ID"); 
    } else if (!password) {
        hasError = true;
        alert("Please enter Password");
    }

    if (!hasError) {
        if(username == "Temp" && password == "123"){
            alert("Login Successful!!");
            window.location = "C:\Users\metyagi\Downloads\Personal data\THE SCM QUIZ\WelcomePage.html";     
        } else {
            alert("Username or Password is incorrect, Please try again!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou ...!! It worked but the entered username gets reset on clicking OK for password alert.